# Are there any game engines in C# or Java that are cross-platform and support multitouch input?

Tags: c#, java, cross-platform, multitouch

I'm looking for game engines (particularly 2D) that can run/create games for Windows, Mac, and Linux, and support multitouch inputs and gestures. I'm able to find many that meet the first two criteria, but don't mention anything about multitouch.

I know that Qt is an existing non-game framework that supports multitouch and is cross-platform. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be geared for hardware-accelerated games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Unity iOS Pro](http://unity3d.com/) but as MrCranky said what is the point of having multi-touch support for a platform that doesn't support multi-touch (at the time being?

Comment: The Unity guys have said that they are planning on bringing their iOS-style multitouch abstraction to the platform versions at some point in the future.  It doesn't have linux support, but nobody cares about linux support.

Comment: Sure it supports Linux (Android is Linux) ;) Linux isn't interesting enough platform yet but its far from nobody caring.

Comment: I believe Android is a MOBILE OS and the core is build upon Linux, but its not meant to be a "big OS" for computers. Thats why Google make Chrome OS.

Comment: It twas a joke. I forgot that Unity doesn't support Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer would probably be: because Windows, Mac and Linux are not primarily touch screen platforms, and multi-touch inputs is a concept that only makes any sense on touch screen platforms.

Why would engines support an input mechanism if the platform doesn't? In some cases (e.g. iOS from Mac OS) there's a common framework because the platforms have evolved their existing OS to support touch screen devices (I'm not sure if Windows and Windows Mobile have gone the same route), but that's rather a side effect than a design decision I'm sure.

As pointed out in the comments, the newest revisions of the desktop OSs are starting to embrace touch screen support, a fact of which I was unaware. But still, additional hardware is needed for everything except tablet PCs. And while Wacom input tablets are nice, they are really no substitute for touch input on the same device as the display is rendering.

So we are talking a currently miniscule proportion of the market. That's not likely to change either, until new systems start shipping with multi-touch capable input devices as standard. And since engine creators, like everyone else, only prosper by supporting targets with decent user numbers, I'd still be surprised if there were any engines which fit your criteria. I'd imagine though, if it's a popular input mechanism, demand for the hardware will grow, and existing engines will start to integrate multi-touch support. I'd be wary of any implementations that didn't have multi-touch in as a core design concept though, since it does affect the interfaces all across the UI part of an engine.

Comment: What are you talking about? I have tablet pc that is multitouch compatible. Apple has a new multitouch mouse. Wacom makes an inexpensive multitouch bamboo tablet.

Comment: That might be true, but out-of-the-box how many percent Windows/Mac/Linux support multitouch? On iOS and Android that makes sense since it comes with the package but how many people would be ready to buy multi-touch devices just to play your multi-touch game?

Comment: Moreover, the Windows/Mac/Linux interfaces are not designed for multitouch. It's just a horrible user experience. (Also, Apple's "multitouch mouse" is not what you think it is. It's still a linear pointing device.) So even though it's supported, even people who have the hardware rarely use it in practice.

Comment: Multitouch is quickly growing for desktops.  Yes, it's still a small percentage, but it's likely to grow quickly, especially across laptops, as iPad and Android touch pads grow in popularity.

Comment: From what I understand, Windows 7 and newer versions of Linux support multitouch right out of the box, and there exist frameworks that are cross-platform and support multitouch as well (Qt is one), but they sadly aren't made to be game engines.

Comment: Revised to acknowledge AttackingHobo's comment. I wasn't aware of any mainstream input peripherals, although I did know that tablet PCs have good support for it. The gist of the answer is unchanged though: engine support follows features the users demand, insufficient demand leads to no support. I've never heard any gamers asking for multi-touch support on desktop OSes - it's a whole different paradigm. If they want those sorts of games, they buy them on native touch screen devices.

Comment: Linux has been supporting multi-touch devices since Kernel 2.6.3 and Windows Vista and above all support it. I don't know about OSX but I would assume so. Also I use my touch screen often, usually during RTS games and casual use like web browsing.